# Java Basic Programming, Trying to reverse the array list elements

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I'm trying to reverse the elements of an ArrayList. I am not sure why this is not working.

### Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample1 {

    public ArrayList reverse(ArrayList orig)
    {
        ArrayList reversed = new ArrayList();
        for(int i= orig.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            Object obj= orig.get(i);
            reversed.add(obj);
        }

        System.out.println("Value..." +reversed);    
        return reversed;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sample1 samp= new Sample1();

        System.out.println("Enter element to enter");
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        String a= sc.nextLine();
        ArrayList<String> A= new ArrayList<String>();
        A.add(a);    
        ArrayList<String> B= samp.reverse(A);
        System.out.println("Arraylist" +B);
    }
}
```

Comment: What results do you expect? What results do you get?

Comment: Uhm, your array list contains just one entry... you might want to split the user input before adding it to your list?!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get better responses and fewer downvotes, first go through the [quick tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), then read the help center, especially [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then post your question according to these guidelines.

Comment: You should consider giving your `reverse` method a return type of `ArrayList<String>`. It will compile the way you have it, but the values stored inside will be converted to a more ambiguous type (object), and could lead to unexpected results down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Your program would work almost fine and you should get a reversed list of the `String` elements you have entered in the console.

Meanwhile you can't get a reversed list of a single element list because simply the resulting list will be the same as the argument one and that's is the case with your `main` method:

```
// The argument List is a one item list
ArrayList<String> A= new ArrayList<String>();
A.add(a);

// The resulting list will be identical to the A list as it contains one sole element
ArrayList<String> B= samp.reverse(A);
System.out.println("Arraylist" +B);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is an exercise consider using [Collections.reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-).